# Why does LLVM not perform range analysis on integer values?

Tags: llvm, compiler-optimization

I was looking at the output assembly from the Rust compiler and noticed it was not removing some of the bounds checks as I would have expected. After additional experimentation, I found that the issue seems to be related to LLVM (the compiler/optimizer backend Rust was using). For simplicity I created a simplified C version of what I was seeing before. In this example, you can see it is impossible to reach the `printf` statement since the sum of `a` and `b` will always be greater than or equal to `a`.

```c
void foo(uint8_t a, uint8_t b, uint64_t c) {
    if (((uint64_t) a) + ((uint64_t) b) >= c) {
        return;
    }

    if ((uint64_t) a >= c) {
        // Do something
        printf("foo");
    }
}
```

To my surprise, LLVM (x86-64 clang 17.0.1 with `-O3`; [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/s9cr3farE)) does not optimize away the `printf`. However, GCC (x86-64 GCC 13.2 with `-O3`; [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/37zMcj75j)) is able to correctly determine that the entire function can be optimized to a single `ret` instruction.

---

That being said, the example I gave was attempting to be extra generous to the compiler by choosing types that make it impossible for an integer overflow to occur and isolate the comparison to a single LLVM IR basic-block. For a more common example, lets say all 3 variables are `size_t`. Since C allows for unsigned integer overflow,  simply converting the above example to `size_t` would lead to cases where the `printf` is in fact reachable. Instead, lets add some pre-conditions which put limits on `a` and `b` before the previous code can be executed.

```c
void foo(size_t a, size_t b, size_t c) {
    // Some pre-condition that puts limits on a and b
    if (a > 2048 || b > 1024) {
        // Using __builtin_unreachable() should have the same effect
        return;
    }

    if (a + b >= c) {
        return;
    }

    if (a >= c) {
        printf("foo");
    }
}
```

Once again, GCC is able to optimize everything to a single `ret`, but clang fails to remove the `printf` ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/bxsWdxsfj)). In this case, LLVM would need to perform range analysis across multiple non-looping basic-blocks, but the code above is something I would have expected a major compiler like LLVM to handle with ease.

**Why does LLVM not run optimization passes for simple range analysis of integer values?**

Going into this, I was not expecting it to be able to perform complex range analysis within loops. However, it seems strange that it does not perform such a simple analysis within the scope of a single basic block. With all of the work that has gone into LLVM, I find it highly unlikely no one has though of performing this sort of optimization.

Comment: An even simpler MCVE would just be `*sink = 0;` instead of printf with another arg, or returning 1 vs. 0.  (https://godbolt.org/z/Kj9q46cs4).  Clang misses the optimization there as well.  If there isn't an existing duplicate on https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/, you could report this missed optimization.  I agree, I'd have expected LLVM to figure this out, especially given that GCC is able to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @PeterCordes, I asked this question on the [LLVM discourse forum](https://discourse.llvm.org/t/why-does-llvm-not-perform-range-analysis-on-integer-values/74341).

Their response was that this is a bug in the `ConstraintElimination` pass that they will attempt to fix in later releases. The most likely cause is that it is not explicitly adding predicates saying unsigned values are always greater than or equal to zero.

> **Edit:** As of December 30th, the fix has been merged into LLVM trunk.